# How to format time in ISO 8601 in Twilio API

Tags: python, twilio, iso8601

I'm trying to use Twilio's messaging services to schedule a text, but I can't figure out how to format the time properly. I've pretty much copied the instructions to a T from Twilio's website, but I keep getting an invalid syntax error. Here's the line of code for the send_at variable:

```
send_at=datetime(2022-2-8'T'17:50:00'Z'),
```

How do I format this properly so it'll run? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this timestamp being generated? Are you hard-coding it? The syntax error you're seeing is Python being unable to understand what's in between the parentheses, it doesn't seem syntactically correct.

You could simply use the [`isoformat()` method from Python's datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) instead to convert a regular datetime object to ISO afterwards, example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> x = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 8, 17, 50)
>>> x.isoformat()
'2022-02-08T17:50:00'
```

[Twilio's own docs](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-scheduled-sms-python-twilio) directly suggest this pattern (see the "Send Scheduled SMS in Python" section):

```
message = client.messages.create(
from_=messaging_service_sid,
to='+1xxxxxxxxxx',  # ← your phone number here
body='Friendly reminder that you have an appointment with us next week.',
schedule_type='fixed',
send_at=send_when.isoformat() + 'Z',
)
```

Looks like the only additional detail is appending that 'Z' at the end, which is the only difference between my first snippet and your original example. If there are different docs that you followed that you can share a link to, happy to give more specific advice.

Comment: I was using the guide [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-message&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x). I followed the guide you linked in your answer and coded appropriately. I ran the script and I believe it worked, no errors or anything. I suppose I'll let you know in an hour when the text is scheduled to send! Thank you very much friend.

Comment: Just to follow up here, the [Twilio Python library will serialize this date object for you](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/2d628f456ffaa655427c11062c5e5fdf65e1aeea/twilio/rest/api/v2010/account/message/__init__.py#L91) using [this function](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/2d628f456ffaa655427c11062c5e5fdf65e1aeea/twilio/base/serialize.py#L22). If you pass a date format in, it will be serialized correctly, if you pass in a string it will return the string. So, you can either format it yourself or pass in a date object and it should work.